# ITMS 9000: The binary you upload was invalid- how to fix

Tags: macos, app-store, mac-app-store

I have application (MyApp.app) and i need submit it for Mac App Store.

Before 10.9.5 release I sent the program to the mac app store and all was well.
And after 10.9.5 release i have error while uploading app from Application Loader:

> ITMS 9000: The binary you upload was invalid

I using terminal commands for signing the application and building the product:

```
codesign -f -v -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: my name" --entitlements "plist here" "app here"
productbuild --component "app here" "/Applications" --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: my name" --product "plist here" "pkg file here"
```

I checked sign with command:
spctl -a -t exec -vv "pkg file"
And result
rejected
source=no usable signature

Please help. Before release 10.9.5 all works good.

Comment: you would need to codesign *after* you build your product.  At the same time, in my own codesigning, I use the certificate name `"Developer ID Application: Michael Dautermann"`.  Are you ***certain*** that the certificate name you need to use is `"3rd Party Mac Developer Application: your name"`? Does this certificate exist in your keychain (i.e. check the "Keychain Access" application in `"/Utilities"`)?

Comment: Not helped. I used this command:

codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: my name" --entitlements "entitlements" "pkg"

I have this certificate and it valid.

You have any ideas?